# How to get the VCPU count of an instance in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm trying to fetch timeseries points of VCPU count for a VM instance using `monitoring_v3` API. While reading the documentation, I encountered two metric types

```
instance/cpu/guest_visible_vcpus
instance/cpu/reserved_cores
```

Which metric type is appropriate for VCPU count and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google documents those metrics [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp).

Which one to use depends on what you are trying to measure and the types of instances you are running. In most cases, the `reserved_cores` represents real CPU power. `guest_visible_vcpu` represents what the guest appears to have, which might appear to be a lot more than the reserved amount.

**instance/cpu/guest_visible_vcpu**

> Number of vCPUs visible inside the guest. For many GCE machine types,
> the number of vCPUs visible inside the guest is equal to the
> `compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores` metric. For
> shared-core machine types, the number of guest-visible vCPUs differs
> from the number of resereved cores. For example, e2-small instances
> have two vCPUs visible inside the guest and 0.5 fractional vCPUs
> reserved. Therefore, for an e2-small instance,
> `compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/guest_visible_vcpus` has a value
> of 2 and `compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores` has a
> value of 0.5. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not
> visible for up to 240 seconds.

**instance/cpu/reserved_cores**

> Number of vCPUs reserved on the host of the instance. Sampled every 60
> seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds.